# How to sequence in case of multiple convertors ? Spartacus 3.4.1

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I implemented a custom convertor that does a custom field mapping :

```
export class DCPOccConfiguratorVariantNormalizer extends OccConfiguratorVariantNormalizer {
...
}
```

and configured it via app.module.ts

```
{provide: VARIANT_CONFIGURATOR_NORMALIZER, useExisting: DCPOccConfiguratorVariantNormalizer, multi: true},
```

Now during runtime, both convertors are called (first custom, second standard). Therefore, the custom field mapping of the custom convertor is beeing overwritten again by the standard convertor.

How can the convertor execution sequence be configured? Is there any other way to change the field mapping of a normalizer/convertor?

Comment: If one configures ```{provide: VARIANT_CONFIGURATOR_NORMALIZER, useExisting: DCPOccConfiguratorVariantNormalizer, multi: false},``` it results in errors.ts:30 ERROR Error: Multi-providers mixed with single providers for InjectionToken VariantConfiguratorNormalizer!